# A simple task I thought - Passing data contained in a variable

Tags: c++

I thought this would be simple but I seem to have myself confused. 
I have been learning C++ for some time now and thought I was getting the hang of it. I have moved over to the 'Visual' aspects of it, specifically MFC.

Basically I'm trying to pass a variable from a DLL into a simple static text box on a MFC application.

( This is a plugin for the game rFactor )

This is the code I have in the DLL file ( .hpp )

```
struct TelemInfoBase
{
  float mEngineRPM;              // engine RPM
}
```

And this is the code to put it into the Static text

```
SetDlgItemText(IDC_DRIVER_NAME, TelemInfoBase::mEngineRPM);
```

But I'm getting a 'illegal reference to non-static member' error

I assume I have to define a variable for the data to be stored in and then access that variable, but I can't quite get my head around how to do that.

Would anyone care to point me in the correct direction?

Comment: use `static float mEngineRPM;`

Comment: This has nothing to do with MFC, it's generic C++ stuff. You might want to pick up and follow a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You probably already have a variable for the data, since it wouldn't make much sense to be displaying a variable that has not been set previously. thatvariable.mEngineRPM or p_thatvariable->mEngineRPM would get you access to that existing variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still having trouble.                              SetDlgItemText (IDC_DRIVER_NAME, TelemInfoBase->mEngineRPM);  Gives a compile error of 'illegal use of this type as an expression'                          SetDlgItemText (IDC_DRIVER_NAME, p_TelemInfoBase->mEngineRPM);   Gives a compile error as 'undeclared identifier'             SetDlgItemText (IDC_DRIVER_NAME, TelemInfoBase.mEngineRPM);    Gives the error is 'illegal after UDT  '                                                                     I've run out of ideas now, this may not correct way to do this.